# Convert to pdf "Frame not found in cellmap"

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I'm building an invoice system, first you'll have to fill in the products you want to have on your invoice then it will convert the html view(where it will show the products in a foreach loop) to pdf. But if I have more than 6 products it will throw the following exception:

> Frame not found in cellmap

I know this question has been asked a lot. But it seems there is still no real solution. It occurs when the input on the page is bigger than the first page and it can't jump to a new page so it throws an error:

Already tried a lottt!

This won't work for me:

```
$paper_orientation = 'landscape';
$customPaper = array(0,0,950,950);
$dompdf->set_paper($customPaper,$paper_orientation);
```

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/657

This is my html view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Factuur</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/administration/style.css" media="all" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="clearfix">
      <img src="/administration/logo.png">
      <div id="company">
          <h2 class="name">Company name</h2>
          <div>Address</div>
          <div>zip</div>
          <div><a href="email">email</a></div> 
      </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div id="details" class="clearfix">
        <div id="client">
          <div class="to">{{ $sort == 0 ? 'Offerte' : 'Factuur' }} voor:</div>
          <h2 class="name">{{ $company }}</h2>
          <div class="address">{{ $address }}</div>
          <div class="address">{{ $zip }}</a></div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>{{ $sort == 0 ? 'Offerte' : 'Factuur' }}nummer: {{ $number }}</h1>
          <div class="date">Datum: {{  $date }}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="no">#</th>
            <th class="desc">Beschrijving</th>
            <th class="unit">Prijs</th>
            <th class="qty">Aantal</th>
            <th class="total">Totaal</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($products as $product)
          <tr>
            <td class="no">{{ $product->id }}</td>
            <td class="desc"><h3>{{ $product->title }}</h3>{{ $product->description }}</td>
            <td class="unit">€{{ $product->price }}</td>
            <td class="qty">{{ $product->number }}</td>
            <td class="total">€{{ $product->total }}</td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
      <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2">SUBTOTAAL</td>
            <td>€ {{ $subtotal }}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2">BTW 21%</td>
            <td>€ {{ $btw }}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2">TOTAAL</td>
            <td>€ {{ $total }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
        <div id="notices" class="{{ $sort == 0 ? 'hidePayment' : 'notices' }}">
          <div>BETALING:</div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      KvK nummer:  | BTW nummer: 
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a solution?

Comment: I'm afraid there's not much we can do as the issue you linked is still open since 2013. The only advice I can give you is to switch to something different, like the [pdfmake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake)(used by Invoice Ninja, FYI), [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)(a bit old but still on the list), or a newcomer like [Snappy](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy) (which uses [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html))

Comment: @phaberest oke thanks going to try that.

Comment: @phaberest if I will use laravel-snappy  will the problem be gone?

Comment: It's not related to dompdf, so it's like comparing oranges and apples. If you are allergic to apples, you sure can drink orange juice ;)